# Inserting text gives objectcollection error

Tags: c#, combobox

I want to insert each row in SQL into combobox, where EmployeeID will be combobox Value, and EmployeeFirstName EmployeeLastName will be text of combobox item. However this line

gives me this error:

> *Error    1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection.Insert(int, object)'
>   has some invalid
>   arguments C:\Users\bilgisayar\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs  45  21  WindowsFormsApplication1*

Answer (score 2):

Define a new class

```
public class EmpItem
{
   public int empID;
   public string empName;
}
```

While reading the DataReader create an instance of this class and add it to the combobox items collections. Do not forget to set the DisplayMember and ValueMember of the combobox

```
void comboboxrefresh()
{
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "empName";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "empID";
    cnn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmployeeID,EmployeeFirstName,EmployeeLastName FROM Employees", cnn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            EmpItem ei = new EmpItem() { empID=dr.GetInt32(0), empName = dr.GetString(1) + dr.GetString(2)};
            comboBox1.Items.Add(ei);
        }
    }
    cnn.Close();
}
```

Comment: there was many missing ";" I fixed them, and now I Get Error 1 Invalid expression term ',' C:\Users\bilgisayar\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 47 45 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: @JanAnderssen can you explain what semicolons are missing and where is line 47, columns 45 in the code above?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
comboBox1.Items.Insert(index, dr.GetString(1) + dr.GetString(2));
```

Where `index` is an integer value where you want to insert in combobox

Did you mean this

```
comboBox1.Items.Insert(dr.GetInt32(0), dr.GetString(1) + dr.GetString(2));
```

If you want to just add in combobox try the following

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(1) + dr.GetString(2));
```

I think you're looking for **DataSource**

```
void comboboxrefresh()
{
    cnn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmployeeID, (EmployeeFirstName + EmployeeLastName) as EmployeeName FROM Employees", cnn);
    DataTable table = new Datatable();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.Fill(table);

    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "EmployeeName";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "EmployeeID";

    comboBox1.DataSource = table;

    cnn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Yes, you've to tell where you need to add. Where you want to insert in combobox?

Comment: what do you mean? I have comboBox1 and the data will just come.

Comment: GetInt32 will be value, the others will be combobox item text

Comment: Are you looking for this?

Answer (score 1):

First, use `Add` to add items to the `ComboBox`. Second, I prefer `anonymous type` to fill the `ComboBox` while you use plain native `Sql` and simple `DataReader` immediately inside your form.

```
void comboboxrefresh()
    {
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmployeeID,EmployeeFirstName,EmployeeLastName FROM Employees", cnn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            combobox1.ValueMember = "Id";
            combobox1.DisplayMember = "FullName";

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(
                  new {
                         FullName = dr.GetString(1) + " " + dr.GetString(2), 
                         Id = dr.GetInt32(0)
                      });
            }
        }

        cnn.Close();
    }
```

**Update:**

I noticed that naively adding to the `Item` list is not working! Instead, `DataSource` property of `ComboBox` should be set to desired list. So the working code is as:

```
var list = new List<object>();
combobox1.ValueMember = "Id";
combobox1.DisplayMember = "FullName";
while (dr.Read())
{
   list.Add(
       new {
              FullName = dr.GetString(1) + " " + dr.GetString(2), 
              Id = dr.GetInt32(0)
            });
 }
combobox1.DataSource = list;
```

Comment: If we need to access `SelectedItem` we can't use it. I don't prefer Anonymous type here.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel is right. I couldn't access comboBox1.SelectedValue to make a query.

Comment: @JanAnderssen Define your own class for this purpose. Steve has got an answer for you.:)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You fetched two(basically three) values per row from DB: EmployeeFullName and EmployeeId. You can access EmployeeId through SelectedValue property and (Employee)FullName through Text property. Do you need anything more? I think if your problem remains unchanged this solution is good enough, (although may not be the best for all the cases).

Answer (score 0):

`Items.Insert` is looking for you to Insert at a **specific point** in the ComboBox list.

You want to use `Items.Add`

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(1) + dr.GetString(2) + dr.GetInt32(0));
```

If you want to use `Insert` it would need to be something like this:

```
comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, dr.GetString(1) + dr.GetString(2) + dr.GetInt32(0));
```

Comment: Error 1 No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments C:\Users\bilgisayar\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 45 21 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: you cant use the same arguments.  Notice that I've concatenated the strings.

Comment: but now I have no value.

Comment: Now that we understand what you want...Alireza has the answer.

Comment: no Alireza didn't solve it. When I used comboBox1.SelectedValue I get no result in query