# How to make comboBox SelectedValue equal with SQL table ID

Tags: c#, winforms

I Want to control the make EmployeeID in SQL side to be equal to combobox value, so that when I insert update delete, I directly control items by their value. However I get error when I enter this line. Does anyone know why this occurs?

**NOTE: KennyZ found the solution. Thank you for help, KennyZ.**

```
    void comboboxrefresh()
    {
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmployeeID,EmployeeFirstName,EmployeeLastName FROM Employees", cnn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Insert(dr.GetString(1) + dr.GetString(2), dr.GetInt32(0));
            }
        }

        cnn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you asking this question twice?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058504/combobox-insert-text-and-value-gives-error

Comment: Looking into the dupe - this looks like the correct answer to me: fix the insert line to: comboBox1.Items.Insert(dr.GetInt32(0), dr.GetString(1) + dr.GetString(2));   That is your current top answer.

Comment: Based on the error in the screenshot (*"InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'"*), you try to insert an item at index 1 => **it supposes there is already an item at index 0**. If not, the first item should be at index **0**

Comment: No, in this case, the value you pass is the *index* of the comboboxItem, nothing else (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.insert.aspx)). Steve's answer in your previous question should work.

Comment: And if you did not receive an answer that helps you, Please **EDIT** your previous question instead of creating a exact duplicate.

Comment: @JanAnderssen to let you know why you should modify an existing question instead of asking the same one again, please see this page on duplicate questions:   http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your parameters are backwards.

```
 comboBox1.Items.Insert(dr.GetString(1) + dr.GetString(2), dr.GetInt32(0));
```

should be

```
 comboBox1.Items.Insert(dr.GetInt32(0), dr.GetString(1) + dr.GetString(2));
```

In the future, please don't ask the same question in two threads 1 hour apart.

EDIT: this doesn't work because the Items collection is probably of length zero.  Looking at the documentation, Insert tries to insert at a specific location in the collection.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.insert.aspx

Try this:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(1) + dr.GetString(2));
```

Comment: @JanAnderssen Updated.  Still, you shouldn't ask the same question twice an hour apart.  If you don't get the answer you want within a day, some activity to get more attention is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The integer arguement to the insert method specifies the index where the object will be inserted, not the value associated with the string.

So, what you need is this:

```
    public class cbItem
{
    public string Name;
    public int Value;
    public cbItem(string name, int value)
    {
        Name = name; Value = value;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Generates the text shown in the combo box
        return Name;
    }
}
```

and then you can use:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(New cbItem(dr.GetString(1) + dr.GetString(2), dr.GetInt32(0)));
```